# Make 2 images appear next to each other without space in between them

Tags: includegraphics

The current solution I found with minipages displays the two figures next to each other however it also adds a lot of space inbetween them. I'd like to have the two images be right next to each other with no space.

```
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        \href{https://link}{\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=5cm,keepaspectratio]{"image1".jpg}}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
        \centering
        \href{https://link}{\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=5cm,keepaspectratio]{"image2".jpg}}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't need to do anything: \includegraphics adds no space so just use two \include graphics.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm not sure I follow you. The code I'm using so far uses the \includegraphics twice but it still produces white space in between the two images.

Comment: You do not need minipage etc. Includegraphics is positioned exactly like a letter so `XX` has no space between and `X X`  has a space. You are forcing a space of 0.2\textwidth

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're right! I wasn't aware it could be made so simple. Thank you!

Comment: In addition to the minipage adding space, the `\hfill` is adding as much space as possible.